# How could very similar values of the same data type differ as to their validity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, debugging

In the Http ActionResult method in my MVC app, the ModelState.IsValid() test is failing. Specifically, a datetime value is seen as invalid. Why that would be is the conundrum, as its quasi-twin is accepted as valid. They are connected to the Controller in the same way in the View (HTML):

```
    <input id="BeginDateTime" name="BeginDateTime" required="true" />
    <input id="EndDateTime" name="EndDateTime" required="true" />
```

The relevant Model code:

```
    public DateTime BeginDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
```

The relevant Controller code:

```
var criteria = new CriteriaContract
{
    AutoPurge = true,
    Serial = Serial,
    parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
    type = DatasourceType.ReceiptCollection
};

string bdt = model.BeginDateTime.ToString();
string edt = model.EndDateTime.ToString();
criteria.parameters.Add("BeginDateTime", bdt); 
criteria.parameters.Add("EndDateTime", edt);
```

The values the debugger shows are almost virtually identical; on a recent debugging session, they were:

```
BeginDateTime == "2013-08-19 14:43:12"
EndDateTime == "2013-08-19 14:43:10"
```

So, being of the same data type, being treated the same in the code, and having the same format, how could one of these values be valid (BeginDateTime) whereas its virtually identical twin is seen as invalid?

### UPDATE

It must have been some transient anomaly or cache issue, because Cleaning and Rebuilding *again* finally caused all the values to be seen as valid...go figure.